# Executing Method Sequence

Tags: c#

Well i have an application that will load some data on the startup; However, every method depends on the previous one's collected data. So i wonder how could i create such loading sequence and wait for every method to finish asynchronously in .NET4.

NB: I know that this can be easily achieved with .NET4.5's async \ await feature but i am kinda must stick to .NET4 [for windows XP users].

What i have tried so far is using delegates and events in order to link methods together; However, it turned out to be very missy code.

Comment: Why not using Thread or BackgroundWorker ?

Comment: @Alireza: they produce a very an untraceable/missy code that there i think is another maybe better/cleaner ways to achieve what i want [the loading sequence].

Comment: Task can be "continued with" / chained. Have you tried tasks?

Comment: @Alireza: I wonder in big projects like games, bit programs. How they handle the loading sequences of their applications `especially when every executed method depends on the previous called method collected information`.

Comment: In the most appropriate/clean yet asynchronous approach. As you know in such huge projects there are tons of depending method calls, GUI updates, etc...

Comment: Loading sequences are I/O bound, not CPU bound.  Using threads is pointless, there's still only one disk.  It is in fact harmful, disks don't like to be sent back-and-forth.

Comment: @HansPassant: in fact i wasn't just speaking about the IO/File loading sequences, i am talking about sequencing a bunch of methods each depending on the other collected information. So if some method faile/returned false or something the next one will not execute... I'v successfully/easily done that using async/await; However, i cant do the same thing in a clean/powerful way in .NET 3.5/4. So as i mentioned before think of it like Game/Huge Projects as you need to load tons of things asynchronously but some of them might depend on the other....

Comment: All that without creating thousands of unnecessary lines of codes.

Comment: If every method depends on the previous ones collected data, doesn't that make them synchronous rather than async?

Comment: @MikeGoodwin: So what ?, in fact that a method needs some data in order to be executed doesn't mean that it must be synchronous...

Comment: You can use async/await and still target .NET 4.0. See http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Comment: @YK1: and it will run on XP Sp3 ??

Comment: Also for learning purpose i still need an answer for my question in .NET 3.5,4.

Comment: Yes, that NuGet package will run on XP SP3.  I've used it before for async/await in .NET 4.0.

Comment: @kevo Don't you need VS 2012 to develop with it?

Comment: Yes, you do need VS 2012, but you can still target the .NET 4.0 framework.

Comment: @DanialEugen Accidentally, I encountered a similar situation in my project. After a short moment of thinking, I was shocked how Threads are deceptive. Threads can do jobs in parallel but a part in the thread itself is not parallel to other parts. Other threads also do not depend on any one. If some tasks are bound to each other by the execution order they are not parallel. They form a sequence. Then then whole sequence can be done in a Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `Task.ContinueWith?`

More info see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx

Answer (score -1):

*I'm only addressing the "chaining" problem. Not threads, async or whatever the others are talking :)*

A very simple way is to use an extension method like this:

```
public static TOut Then<TIn, TOut>(this TIn obj, Func<TIn, TOut> convert)
{
  return convert(obj);
}
```

Given a set of methods:

```
string Init();
int Convert(string str);
int Add(int i);
```

You could write: `Init().Then(Convert).Then(Add)` and so on, what also reads pretty nice.

Comment: This doesn't seem remotely applicable to OP's question about running asynchronous operations in sequence.

Comment: Quote from comment: *especially when every executed method depends on the previous called method collected information* Well, I think it is applicable.

Comment: Not when they are asynchronous, which is the key point of the question. You can't just take part of the question out of context and answer that. The return value of an asynchronous method will not typically be the retrieved data, so your approach would not work for that.

Comment: I'm not taking just one piece of the question. He stated that he used delegates but ended up with messy code. I provided some code that is very easy to read. Would it make you happy if I replace `TIn` and `TOut` with `Task<TIn>` and `Task<TOut>`? FYI: You're taking just a piece of my answer. I underlined that I'm only addressing the input/output issue.